# Upload a file to a model ID subdir

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I’m creating fitness Exercises in Nova and use native File and Image fields to handle uploads. However, I’d like the files to be stored in a sub directory with model ID:

```
- public
  - media
    - {id}
      - video.mp4
      - image.jpeg
```

This works fine when updating an existing model (the ID is already available), but the files are uploaded to base upload path `public/media` for new Exercises. This means model ID is not available during file upload yet.

Is it possible to achieve this in any other way? How would you do it, e.g.:

- can you somehow queue uploads (which would be good to speed things up for admins too)? Queued tasks should be able to access model ID, right? Couldn’t find any docs about queues in Nova though.
- listen to `created` event, get the ID, create dir, move files and update database fields? Sounds doable but quite some extra work.
- write custom `store` procedures for media files and handle it there? Will it run after the model is created or still before saving it to the database so no ID is available?
- just replace the ID with some unique string that can be generated upfront and appended to a path instead? How would you store it so it’s accessible for subsequent edits? Get it from saved media file path every time or store as a separate field in database?

I’m new to both Laravel and Nova and don’t know the best practices yet. Would appreciate any help/advice on this.

Comment: Can't you just handle the image upload after the model creation block? `$model = Model::create($params); $model_id = $model->id; $path = "storage/app/public/media/$model_id/$filename.$fileExt";`

Comment: @stokoe0990 not sure how to do it in the Laravel Nova context. Studied  Laravel\Nova\Resource file and. Laravel\Nova\Fields\File to understand how things work, didn't help.

Comment: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#image-field

This should be all you need, really. Nova has built-in support for image fields.

Comment: @stokoe0990 I am already using the built-in Image field which is clearly stated at the beginning of my question. And I've studied the docs long before asking the question. Image field picks up the ID and creates directory if you're editing the existing model. But if you're creating a new entry, Nova first uploads the file, populates model properties and then saves to database, thus, the ID is not available at this point. Hence, my question.

Comment: Perhaps a [Resource Event](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/#resource-events) is more along the lines of what you need then?

Comment: This actually makes sense. Somehow I didn't notice this part of the documentation, thank you for pointing this out. I do need it only on Nova requests so it makes more sense to handle events on Nova level.